# How can I enable parenthesis matching highlighting in string literals with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

I am working on a C# project that has many large SQL string literals. It would be very helpful to have the editor highlight matching parentheses inside the literals (as is available in C# code). Is there any way to enable this in VS2012? Alternatively, is there a free plugin that does this?

Comment: `I am working on a C# project that has many large SQL string literals` - Use an ORM instead. putting SQL strings in code is a crappy dinosaur practice no body uses today. There `might` be some very specific cases where you will want to deal with the SQL yourself, but the `vast` majority of your data access should already be ORMed by now.

Comment: This might be legacy code? He's not going to replace with an ORM?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3a662c6-28eb-4de9-9a29-d328b1ac3f6b

q=visual+studio+sql+string+literal+highlighter

Comment: Interesting... I don't see parenthesis matching in their list of features, but I can give this a try.